# NOPcommerce 1.80 page title store prefix -> suffix

Tags: store, title, nopcommerce

Is there a way, in NOP, to use the store prefix as a suffix and modify it a bit? For instance, I would like to transform this:

`{prefix}. {title}`

to

`{title} | {prefix}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: anyone? I really need to know where this is!

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be nopCommerce 1.80?

In the latest version 2.40 you change this under General And Miscellaneous Settings -> SEO Settings.

Change `page title separator` to ' | ' and `page title SEO adjustment` to 'Page name comes after store name'.

[edit] Based on your comment that you have to use v1.80 the following would apply:

You have to edit the `RenderTitle` method in the `NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.SEO.SEOHelper` class to override the default page title format.

In your case you would want to have something like:

```
public static void RenderTitle(Page page, string title, 
        bool includeStoreNameInTitle, bool overwriteExisting)
{
    if (page == null || page.Header == null)
        return;

    /* Change starts here */

    if (includeStoreNameInTitle)
        title = title + " | " + SettingsManager.StoreName;

    /* Change ends here */ 

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
        return;

    if (overwriteExisting)
        page.Title = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(title);
    else
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(page.Title))
            page.Title = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it has to be 1.80. It's quite a complex nop mixed with wordpress. I cannot upgrade it, even though it would be my best solution. I'm sure I could re-write this functionnality in the code somewhere, I just don't know where.